# How to set the size of div in asp.net using vb code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

setting the size of div in HTML:

```
height: 1000px;
```

Is it possible to set the size of a div in asp.net using vb code? what i mean is how can i put a mark up language in a vb code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off if you want to access the `Div` from your code behind you've gotta make sure it has the `runat="server"` and `ID="SomeID"` attributes set, then you can access it from code behind like any other Asp.Net control.

Markup:

```
<div runat="server"  id="myDiv"></div>
```

VB.Net

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        myDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "height:1000px")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it's working, but how can I access div of different webform?

Comment: This is another question. Please ask another question, accept this as your answer if it worked, and share the link to that question so that we can help you.

Comment: Good, don't forget to share the link to the new question.