# how can I access a div of different webform?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

[How to set the size of div in asp.net using vb code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14995861/how-to-set-the-size-of-div-in-asp-net-using-vb-code/14995939#comment21063308_14995939)

This question is about accessing a div and set its height. And the answer from this question is correct.

Now I want to ask how can I access a div of different webform?

have two webforms, example is Default1.aspx and Default2.aspx, the webform Default1.aspx is inside an Iframe, and then the Iframe is inside the div of Default2.aspx. In my webform Default1.aspx, I have a button, and code behind the button event is to set the size of the div of Default2.aspx. Hope you understand

Comment: Do you need to access to modify the div, or to read from the div?

Comment: I need to access to modify the div, specifically its height

Comment: Do you set some value in say Default1.aspx and then when you submit this form you redirect to say Default2.aspx, and it is here where you want to set the value for your div?

Comment: uhmm sorry but I cannot clearly understand your answer, I will rephrase it, In my webform Default1.aspx I have a button, that button have a code to set the size of the dive of Default2.aspx. And I forgot to tell that Default1.aspx is inside an Iframe, and that Iframe is inside the div of Default2.aspx. I hope you understand this.

Comment: Are you creating a popup window or what? I mean can you elaborate the scenario a bit?

Comment: Ahhhhh! That makes much more sense now.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro please include the detail explanation in your question. You're actual requirement is not obvious from the question itself.

Comment: OK sir i will edit my question.

Comment: I already edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I made it work, you just need some javascript:

Form1:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script>
    function changeDiv() {
        frames["myiFrame"].document.getElementById("divInFrame").setAttribute("style", "height:1000px");
    }
    </script>
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="changeDiv();" />
    <iframe src="Default2.aspx" style="border: 0px #FFFFFF none;" name="myiFrame" id="myiFrame"
        scrolling="no" frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="60px"
        width="468px"></iframe>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Form2:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="divInFrame">
      I am the second form!
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So basically this line is in charge of doing everything:

```
frames["myiFrame"].document.getElementById("divInFrame").setAttribute("style", "height:1000px");
```

Note that using this approach you do not necesarily need to set the height from Vb, like in your previous question, you just need a normal HTML div.

Comment: I edited some codes, and it is smoothly working now! thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access that div directly but you can produce a similar effect by storing a session variable.  In the web form that has the div that you want to alter you would use the Page_Load event handler to check to see if that session variable exists and then set the div's height using that variable's value.

**Edit**

I created a test page to see if this method works with an iframe and it does seem to.  The code I used was:

in the main page

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Session("divHeight") = "100px"
End Sub
```

in the secondary page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("divHeight") Is Nothing Then
        divTest.Style.Add("height", "50px")
    Else
        divTest.Style.Add("height", Session("divHeight"))
    End If
End Sub
```

This resulted in the div in question doubling in height when the button is pressed.

Just for an alternate method.

Comment: see my comment in my question, hope you understand

Comment: This method does seem to work due to the fact that when you press the button the page is reloaded and the Page_Load is run again.

Comment: thanks for adding a comment, I forgot that you edited your answer, ok sir i will try it too

Answer (score 0):

you can access a div when you load the webform you can not access it from an other webform because when a webform loaded it download every thing to your browser(client side) and the other webform will be in the server side.